# changing default article font colour

Tags: tinymce

I'm having trouble with my article font colour.
The Default Font colour in TinyMce is "No Colour". And I have to constantly change the font colour to black.
It is not too much of a problem, but it has had a rollover effect onto my Default pages like my login page. The text doesn't show as it is obviously set to default "No Colour".

I have scoured global settings and The System, also the TinyMce module settings but nothing seems to do it.

Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: That would usually be set in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'No color' is the correct option. You should add some custom css to your site to control the the colour of your text.  Note: the 'no color' option does not mean transparent; it means no inline style will be applied to the html tag by the editor.  If you cannot see the text, then you have a css problem, not a wysiwyg problem.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Turned out I had an override in my CSS

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with your template. If this is a template you purchased, you may want to contact the developer that produced it. If you are comfortable with editing CSS code, then you may want to take a look at the [Joomla Documentation for modifying a template](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template).